# PhpStorm tabs color

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, intellij-idea

Что обозначают различные цвета заголовка файлов (tabs color) ?

Comment: SO не должен заменять справку по конкретной программе

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Этот флаг актуален, если вы используете **File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | File Colors**

Вы задаете цветовую схему для файлов проекта на основе регулярных выражений. И, если этот флаг поставлен, то цветовые изменения будут также накладываться и на *заголовки/вкладки* открытых файлов [image: Цветные табы].

Доп инфо: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/file-colors.html

Answer (score 0):

Если различается цвет фона, см. ответ [Adobe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179181/adobe);
Если различие в цвете шрифтов, это может быть связано с использованием версионного контроля - имена файлов будут окрашены по-разному в зависимости от статуса файла. Цвет можно настроить в **File | Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | File Status**